# Meteor - How to call an external class methods from other JS files?

Tags: javascript, oop, meteor, instantiation

I'm new to meteor. I've been trying to write my meteor code the "object-oriented way" so I created an object called Message for my Parser and called it's methods from my app.js.

I would like to instantiate the object and call the methods defined in my Message.JS from my app.js?

### App structure

App 
      |--app.html 
      |--app.js 
      |--app.css 
      |--message.js 
      |--.meteor 

**message.js**

```
  var Message = {


    init: function( message ){

   /* Initialization function with some properties */

   }

  getHash: function() {
    return this.hash_table;
   }

  parseMessage: function(input) {

 /* Some Parsing logic */

  return(hash_table);
 }
 }
```

**app.js**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

 var msg = new Message.init(response);
 var hash =  msg.getHash();
 console.log(hash);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared with var have a file scope in Meteor, and cannot be accessed from within other files.
If you declare the variable without var, it will have a bigger scope and can be seen from within your app,

```
Message = {
    ...
}
```

If that doesn't work, you might have a problem with the load order. The code in message.js should be loaded before the code in app.js gets called. To make sure it is, put message.js in the /lib folder. Files in this folder are always loaded before everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But declaring Message as a global variable without var, doesn't work. How can you import a class from the app.js?

Comment: @MariusDarila Added the App structure in the main description

Comment: I think it's a problem with load order. Try adding the message js to the lib folder. By the way, you can't instantiate an object that is no function, so new Message.init() won't work. Try var msg = Message.init(response); Or, if you need multiple message objects Message = function (message) { this.message = message } and var msg = new Message(response);

Answer (score 0):

Add message.js into a folder named lib so it gets loaded first when meteor starts see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/examplefilestructure. Then just remove var from Message so it becomes global.